# How to run a Python file in c++?

Tags: python, c++

I have spent a good part of my day trying to run a Python file from c++. I have tried:

```
. . .

FILE * file = fopen ("file.py", "r");

PyRun_SimpleFile (file, "file.py");

. . .
```

This however just causes my application to crash. I am using python version 3.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleFile (file, "file.py");
Py_Finalize();
```

Comment: Also possibly dumb, but make sure that you're doing `#include <Python.h> `

Comment: Now if I run the code it says File "file.py", line 1 ufffd/ufffd/ufffd/etc.

Comment: Well it is loading the python file but I'm getting that weird error

Comment: Perhaps post the code that prints, or the contents of the python file.